# Instantianting a SunPKCS11 with a config from a ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11

I want to achieve this:

```
private static InputStream getTokenCfg() {
    String cfg = MessageFormat.format(
            "name = {0} /n library = {1} /n  slotListIndex = 0",
            config.getPkcs11().getKey(),
            config.getPkcs11().getValue());

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(cfg.getBytes());
}
```

and then use it with `new SunPKCS11(getTokenCfg());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Curiously enough, I just wronged the string...
rsss....
The following `"name = {0} \r\nlibrary = {1} \r\nslotListIndex = 0"`, works like a charm..
Silly me, I mistook the newline and forgot the carriage-return char...

Comment: No. You wrote a forward slash instead of a backslash. The carriage return isn't required.